# How do I extract certain parts of strings in Python?

Tags: python, string

Say I have three strings:

> abc534loif
>
> tvd645kgjf
>
> tv96fjbd_gfgf

and three lists:

- `beginning` captures just the first part of the string "the name"
- `middle` captures just the number
- `end` contains only the rest of the characters that are after the number portion

How do I accomplish this in the most efficent way?

Comment: Why does it need to be efficient? Also, what have you tried so far? Also, do you only have 1 such string? Why the lists then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regular expressions?

```
>>> import re
>>> strings = 'abc534loif tvd645kgjf tv96fjbd_gfgf'.split()
>>> for s in strings:
...   for match in re.finditer(r'\b([a-z]+)(\d+)(.+?)\b', s):
...     print match.groups()
... 
('abc', '534', 'loif')
('tvd', '645', 'kgjf')
('tv', '96', 'fjbd_gfgf')
```

Comment: wouldn't be easier with `re.split(r'(\d+)', s)`?

Comment: that's a nice idea, if the `s` is already known to be in the right format (i.e. not with other spam prepended/appended on the line)

Answer (score 1):

This is language agnostic approach that aims at higher efficiency:

1. find first digit in the string and save its position `p0`
2. find last digit in the string and save its position `p1`
3. extract substring from `0` to `p0-1` into `beginning`
4. extract substring from `p0` to `p1` into `middle`
5. extract substring from `p1+1` to `length-1` into `end`

Comment: This is not as robust as a regex.  For example, it would fail for a non-match like `"abc123spam456def"`

Comment: @wim: Well, it's equally robust if you just don't allow bad input.

Comment: and how do you filter out bad input.. with a regex?  ;)

Comment: @wim: Via specification (like design-by-contract).

Comment: @wim - the specification (question) clearly asks for 2 things: parsing exact format of the string, efficiency. I agree with Niklas on all points. We can agree that this gives us as good output as input was or fails if digits are not found (per contract).

Comment: Fair enough.  We can agree to disagree, I think that "_robust if you just don't allow bad input_" is an oxymoron.. robustness means something more than correctness!

Comment: @wim: No, it's how design by contract works: You only ensure the correct result for valid input. It's then up to the caller if he wants to ensure all preconditions or live with the consequences.

Comment: I'm not saying there's anything wrong with design-by-contract.  I'm saying that an algorithm which isn't aware/doesn't tell you when it's screwing up is not _robust_.

Comment: @wim - we don't have to disagree. But if the question mentioned robustness then everyone would be checking for nulls, non-ascii characters, empty strings, etc. etc. But question didn't mention it. It did mention efficiency though. Stating and solving problems the author of question is not interested in helps our own ego though.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking for [re.findall](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
strs = """
    abc534loif
    tvd645kgjf
    tv96fjbd_gfgf
"""

import re
print re.findall(r'\b(\w+?)(\d+)(\w+)', strs)

>> [('abc', '534', 'loif'), ('tvd', '645', 'kgjf'), ('tv', '96', 'fjbd_gfgf')]
```

Comment: use `zip(*re.findall(r'\b(\w+?)(\d+)(\w+)', strs))` to produce the 3 lists :)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> s="abc534loif"
>>> [''.join(j) for i,j in it.groupby(s, key=str.isdigit)]
['abc', '534', 'loif']
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouls use regualar expressions like:

```
(?P<beginning>[^0-9]*)(?P<middle>[^0-9]*)(?P<end>[^0-9]*)
```

and pull out the three matching sections.

```
import re 

m = re.match(r"(?P<beginning>[^0-9]*)(?P<middle>[^0-9]*)(?P<end>[^0-9]*)", "abc534loif")
m.group('beginning')
m.group('middle')
m.group('end')
```

Comment: It should be (?P<middle>[0-9]*), i.e. no '^' to match the middle part, right? And it's probably better to use '+' than '*'.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re #You want to match a string against a pattern so you import the regular expressions module 're'
mystring = "abc1234def" #Just a string to test with
match = re.match(r"^(\D+)([0)9]+](\D+)$") #Our regular expression. Everything between brackets is 'captured', meaning that it is accessible as one of the 'groups' in the returned match object. The ^ sign matches at the beginning of a string, while the $ matches the end. the characters in between the square brackets [0-9] are character ranges, so [0-9] matches any digit character, \D is any non-digit character.
if match: # match will be None if the string didn't match the pattern, so we need to check for that, as None.group doesn't exist.
    beginning = match.group(1)
    middle = match.group(2)
    end = match.group(3)
```

Comment: There's an underscore in one of the strings. Maybe \D would be better than [a-zA-Z]?

Answer (score 0):

I'd something like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> l = ['abc534loif', 'tvd645kgjf', 'tv96fjbd_gfgf']
>>> regex = re.compile('([a-z_]+)(\d+)([a-z_]+)')
>>> beginning, middle, end = zip(*[regex.match(s).groups() for s in l])
>>> beginning
('abc', 'tvd', 'tv')
>>> middle
('534', '645', '96')
>>> end
('loif', 'kgjf', 'fjbd_gfgf')
```